How can I embed a document?
I'd like for a button on my navigation bar to navigate to a pdf viewer showing my resume. Right now I'm seeing an error message saying the file cannot be viewed. I've downloaded so many packages following different tutorials on how to do this.
Component:
import React from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
import AbigailFigaroResume from '../assets/pdf/AbigailFigaroResume.pdf';

export default function Resume() {
    return (
        <Document file={AbigailFigaroResume}>
            <Page pageNumber={1} />
        </Document>
    );
}

Router:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import Projects from './components/Projects.jsx';
import Project from './pages/Project.jsx';
import Resume from './pages/Resume.jsx';
import Login from './pages/Login.jsx';
import Error from './pages/Error.jsx';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Login />,
    errorElement: <Error />
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <Error />
  },
  {
    path: '/projects',
    element: <Projects />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/projects/:projectId',
        element: <Project />
      }
    ],
    errorElement: <Error />
  },
  {
    path: '/resume',
    element: <Resume />,
    errorElement: <Error />
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router = { router } />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

Package Json:
{
  "name": "personalwebsite",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "nodemon vite.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer": "^1.15.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.4.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "react-on-screen": "^2.1.1",
    "react-pdf": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "description": "This template provides a minimal setup to get React working in Vite with HMR and some ESLint rules.",
  "main": "vite.config.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

I tried installing a few packages recommended by tutorials on YouTube. None of them worked fully for me. I get an error message where I expect to see a PDF view.
